# Imports and order in sys.path problem: can't run pytest from top directory

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I have a project with package inside a package. Each of the packages has its own `test` directory with `context.py` files inside and tests. When I run `pytest` from within either `test` directory, all works fine. But I'd prefer to by able to run `pytest` once from the top and do not be bothered by changing directories. Here I prepared a minimal example mimicking it:

```
./a
./a/b
./a/b/__init__.py
./a/b/test
./a/b/test/test_b.py
./a/b/test/context.py
./a/__init__.py
./a/test
./a/test/test_a.py
./a/test/context.py
```

content of files:
a/test/context.py:

```
class A():
    pass
```

a/b/test/context.py:

```
class B():
    pass
```

a/test/test_a.py:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)

import context
print('context.__file__', context.__file__)

from context import A

def test_stub():
    pass
```

a/b/test/test_b.py:

```
from context import B

def test_stub():
    pass
```

When `pytest` is run in either `a/test` or `a/b/test` it works fine. Nevertheless, when run in just `a` (where I would expect it to collect and execute all nested tests) it throws the following exception:

```
=============================================================================================== test session starts ===============================================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.7.4, pytest-5.2.1, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.13.0
rootdir: /home/maciek/tmp/pytestp/a
plugins: remotedata-0.3.2, openfiles-0.4.0, arraydiff-0.3, doctestplus-0.4.0
collected 1 item / 1 errors                                                                                                                                                                                       

===================================================================================================== ERRORS ======================================================================================================
_________________________________________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting test/test_a.py _________________________________________________________________________________________
ImportError while importing test module '/home/maciek/tmp/pytestp/a/test/test_a.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
test/test_a.py:7: in <module>
    from context import A
E   ImportError: cannot import name 'A' from 'context' (/home/maciek/tmp/pytestp/a/b/test/context.py)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
['/home/maciek/tmp/pytestp/a/test', '/home/maciek/tmp/pytestp/a/b/test', '/home/maciek/anaconda3/bin', ...]
context.__file__ /home/maciek/tmp/pytestp/a/b/test/context.py
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
================================================================================================ 1 error in 0.09s =================================================================================================
```

where I removed the remainder of the whole `sys.path`. The important bit is in its beginning:
`'/home/maciek/tmp/pytestp/a/test'` comes before `'/home/maciek/tmp/pytestp/a/b/test'`, yet when I import `context`, the one from `'/home/maciek/tmp/pytestp/a/b/test'` is being imported, which is indicated by the line: `context.__file__ /home/maciek/tmp/pytestp/a/b/test/context.py` and the fact that exception is being thrown.

Why is it so? Why does not the import seem to be respecting the order of entries in `sys.path` (Aa I would expect it according to [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so it seems that once context is imported, further imports of context do nothing (although we mean a different file with the same name). Apparently Python thinks the module is already imported. Adding

```
from importlib import reload
reload(context)
```

after each import context fixes the issue. But I don't think it is a perfect solution, since I think `reload` is known not to work perfectly